# How to use a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) custom Connection Manager programmatically?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to programmatically create an SSIS package from a C# console application that uses a 3rd party Custom Connection Manager for Kafka like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    Application app = new Application(); 
    Package pkg = new Package(); 
    ConnectionManager cmKafka = pkg.Connections.Add("KAFKACS"); 
...
```

which fails with:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException 
> The connection type "KAFKACS" specified for connection manager ... is not
> recognized as a valid connection manager type.

Adding this manager to an Integration Services Project from Visual Studio 2017 works just fine, however.

I am new to SSIS, C# and Windows development. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Add GAC references to KAFKACS assemblies to my console application.
- Force 64bit execution which results in `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap` not found.
- Use reflection to try to figure out what architecture and for what .NET framework version the Kafka DLLs I reference target (looks like MSIL).
- Create versions of the same application using previous versions of .NET target framework.
- Try to manually create an instance of the Kafka manager as shown here:

```
var rawKafka = new KafkaConnectionManager(); 
ConnectionManager cmKafka = (???) rawKafka; 
pkg.Connections.Join(cmKafka);
```

- Do I need to register the KAFKACS component in order for the call to `Connections.Add` to succeed?
- Are the error messages misleading and I am missing other, perhaps Kafka specific assemblies I need to reference?
- Can I manually create a instance of the `KafkaConnectionManager` and use it with `Connections.Join`?

Comment: What is the end objective? To ingest data using kafka? I'm always wary of complicated solutions where a simple solution will suffice. Why not just use a C# console app to ingest the Kafka data directly? SSIS is now an old technology in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid the objective is to automate the generation of SSIS packages on a project where SSIS, Kafka as well as the custom manager are already widely used for this sort of integration.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question, the issue had been that the 3rd party Connection Manager was build for SQL Server 2017 (v14) but the console application referenced the `ManagedDTS` assembly for 2016 (v13).

The call to `pkg.Connections.Add("KAFKACS")` could not find the DLLs since the 3rd Party installer had installed them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Connections` (where 140 corresponds to v14) and not in `\130\DTS\Connections` where v13 of `ManagedDTS` would expect to find them.